# Structure Tensor for Lucas and Kanade

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opticalflow

for an university task im currently implementing Lucas and Canade in OpenCV with Python, but the results are not as expected:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

#begin func
def calculate_lc_displacement(img1,img2,imgsmooting,p):
    #smooth image

    if imgsmooting > 0:
        img1 = cv.GaussianBlur(img1, (0,0), imgsmooting)
        img2 = cv.GaussianBlur(img2, (0,0), imgsmooting)

    #calc gradients
    dx = cv.Sobel(img1, cv.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize = 3, scale = 1.0/3.0)
    dy = cv.Sobel(img1, cv.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize = 3, scale = 1.0/3.0)

    #calc temporal gradient
    dt = img2-img1

    #compute structure tensor components
    axx = cv.GaussianBlur(dx * dx, (0,0), p)
    ayy = cv.GaussianBlur(dy * dy, (0,0), p)
    axy = cv.GaussianBlur(dx * dy, (0,0), p)

    
    bx = cv.GaussianBlur(dx * dt, (0,0), p)
    by = cv.GaussianBlur(dy * dt, (0,0), p)

    #compute u and v according to lecture
    norm = (axx*ayy) - (axy*axy)
    u = ( (bx * ayy) - (axy * by)) / norm
    v = ( (by* axx) - (axy * bx) ) / norm
    return u,v
#endfuc

#get imgs
I1g = cv.imread(r"C:\Users\Tobias\Desktop\pyhonws\lucaskanada\yos1.pgm", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
I2g = cv.imread(r"C:\Users\Tobias\Desktop\pyhonws\lucaskanada\yos2.pgm", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
#calc displacement
u,v = calculate_lc_displacement(I1g,I2g,1.4,6.4)

# Use Hue, Saturation, Value colour model 
img3 = cv.imread(r"C:\Users\Tobias\Desktop\pyhonws\lucaskanada\yos1.pgm", cv.IMREAD_COLOR) #for 3 dimensions
hsv = np.zeros(img3.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
mag, ang = cv.cartToPolar(u,v)
hsv[..., 1] = 255
hsv[..., 0] = ang * 180 / np.pi / 2
hsv[..., 2] = cv.normalize(mag, None, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
bgr = cv.cvtColor(hsv, cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cv.imshow("colored flow", bgr)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Does anyone see what is wrong with the code?
The function showing the displacement is actually correct, it works fine with the openCV implementation of Lucas and Canade.

The disparity map given on the yosemite sequence is totally not matching those given in the example.

expected for parameters is this:

[image: should be]

but it looks like this:

[image: results]

and here is a visualisation of the intermediate steps:

[image: intermediateResulsts]

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong with the code? On first look it seems correct. Please include a full description of the issue you ran into.

Comment: `but the results are not as expected` how so? What is your expected result vs. what are you getting?

Comment: so i edited the code for the full answer

Comment: Maybe show your output and your expected output? It is hard to diagnose a problem based on just "totally not matching". The only issue I've spotted so far is a missing minus sign for vector *b*.

Comment: oh yes, with the minus sign i already tried, but it didnt really changed much

Comment: The intermediate images don't help much, the display is clipped (negative values all shown as pure black, values above 1 all shown as pure white). I recommend that you min/max normalize the image to the [0,1] range before display.

Comment: When you do `dt = img2-img1`, what is the data type of the output? Is this an 8-bit unsigned operation, leading to overflow? You need to ensure that this operation uses floating-point arithmetic and that `dt` is a floating-point image. `dx` and `dy` should be OK, it seems you request a floating-point output there.